# Error running '__rvm_make -j4' when installing ruby 2.1.10 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-18.04

I was doing set up a rails project which was on ruby-2.1.10 and rails-4.1.4.
I tried a lot of solutions but nothing has worked for me, It already took my one day. 
please help me to resolve this If anyone can help or already faced this issue.

**solutions which I have tried.**

**1)**

```
rvm install 2.1.10
```

**2)**

```
rvm get head

rvm install 2.1.10
```

**3)**

```
rvm get master

rvm install ruby-2.1.10
```

**4)**

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev ruby-dev

rvm reinstall 2.1.10 --force
```

**5)**

```
 rvm get head

 rvm reinstall all
```

I also tried to reinstall rvm and ruby using rbenv,
using rvm, using source files
 from this [link](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/18.04)

each time I was facing this issue

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /home/mds/.rvm/log/1525769841_ruby-2.1.10/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

When I opened this file /home/mds/.rvm/log/1525769841_ruby-2.1.10/make.log

This is the log file [link](https://github.com/vin-droid/error-files/blob/master/make.log).

Comment: I had massive problems over the weekend with both rvm and rbenv on a fresh linux install - this helped me get some working with rbenv where I had the same error as you: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/834 (it's something to do with SSL apparently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try this:

```
rvm reload
rvm install ruby-2.1.10
```

If you get same errors try installing with this patch, based on @mark 's comment,
you can use a patch file, but of course you probably wanna view the patch before running, it seems to correct SSL version problems.

View the patch from [here](https://gist.github.com/mislav/055441129184a1512bb5.txt)

Then try install your version with the patch:

```
rvm install ruby-2.1.10 --patch https://gist.github.com/mislav/055441129184a1512bb5.txt
```

Comment: thanks @lacoster
Before using this patch I just tried 
 
rvm get head
 
rvm reload

 rvm install ruby-2.1.1

 rvm install ruby-2.1.10

now it's working, I don't how.

Comment: rvm reload
rvm install ruby-2.1.10

I already tried these before installing ruby-2.1.1 It didn't work for me that time.

Answer (score 1):

**I had same issue, installing 2.1.10.
Solution that worked for me.**

```
rvm get master
rvm reload
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 2.2.10 --force -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```